# Why have I become invisible?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After Brelyna in the College of Winterhold "experimented" on me, I became invisible. Now I am unable to see my character at all. Is this just a glich; is there anything I can do short of starting a new game?

Comment: Your entire character or can you see the clothes but not the person in them? (I know there is a glitch with some things you get from the college that will make you a walking pile of clothes, hehe)

Comment: I tried changing clothes to see if it would fix itself, I tried sleeping and fast traveling and etc.. Under active affects in the magic section it showed Bre's spell and I waited for it to wear off(like the first time) but nothing changed. I can still interact with the world like normal but I can't see my character, her clothes or her weapons. It's really annoying. and of course I saved since this happened so theres no going back...

Comment: If it makes any difference... when Bre turned me into a horse and then back again to myself; the horse is still in the room where this transpired. I killed the horse and nothing changed. I will probably just start a new game... f*$#!

Comment: [How to solve the Player Becomes Invisible bug?](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/articles/3821) - it's usually hair; SMP or HDT.

Answer (score 8):

*Edit:* None of these seemed to work for the OP, but I'll leave them here as suggestions for those experiencing similar issues.

For the why, well, I have no idea (aside from "oh, Bethesda"). But I had a similar issue with a spell effect being permanently attached to my feet. It generated smoke, so my sneaky little thief looked something like Smoke from Mortal Kombat. I gamboled about until it finally resolved, I believe due to transformation into a werewolf. Your problem is due to either opacity (most likely) being set to 0 or your character model being non-existent (unlikely IMO).

There are several solutions I'll suggest:

**Become Ethereal:**
The [Become Ethereal](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Become_Ethereal) shout should fix any opacity issues when it ends. [Here's a YouTube video from a user with a similar issue](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=33_WLPPAr6w). Although it ends with the person just reloading a save and exacting revenge, the user claims that the suggestion to use Become Ethereal repaired the problem.

Become Ethereal's Words can be found in [Lost Valley Redoubt](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lost_Valley_Redoubt), [Ironbind Barrow](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ironbind_Barrow) and [Ustengrav](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ustengrav). If you can handle Hagravens and a few Forsworn, Lost Valley Redoubt's Word Wall is outside and probably the quickest.

There are also unique potions that let you become ethereal, called [Philters of the Phantom](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Philter_of_the_Phantom#Philter_of_the_Phantom). You can find them in [a quest in Shroud Hearth Barrow](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lifting_the_Shroud), near Ivarstead. It's possible that an invisibility spell or potion will have the same effect, but I haven't tried that or seen it done.

**Console (PC only):**
Open the console (<kbd>~</kbd> or whatever's above <kbd>tab</kbd> and left of <kbd>1</kbd>) and type

```
player.setactoralpha 100
```

If that doesn't work, there's

```
sexchange
sexchange
```

It should force your character model to, uh, rebuild.

**Werewolf:**
Transforming to a Werewolf and back will also force rebuilding.

Comment: Nothing I tried seemed to work: drinking potions or Becoming Ethereal (I already had that shout, good suggestion tho). I didn't try to become a werewolf, so that may still be a possibility. I don't think it would have worked tho, this was a serious glitch. I ended up starting a new game today; this was my first character and now I have a better idea of where to go and what to do. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: The player.setactoralpha 100 worked for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks guys! I tried the Become Ethereal thing and fast traveled right away and it worked! Again thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm dealing with the Breylin glitch too - now my character is invisible, and I don't have a save to load.

I tried the werewolf and no dice. Instead of walking and trying to get all the shouts to become ethedral (and doing all that while invisible which sucks), I decided to try my own thing.

So first invisibility potion, then I walked in a door while still invisible. I could see my weapons but nothing else.

Then I used a appear spectral (like a ghost) and you could see him but ghostly. I walked outside, waited for potion to wear off and - boom fixed - I can now see my character again!

Answer (score 2):

I did some research a while ago for my own purposes and it turns out that using Become Ethereal and then fast traveling RIGHT after using it will you turn back to normal.  This also works with the phantom potion everyone is talking about (Philter of the Phantom? Look it up).  Results can be varied though, sometimes fast traveling is not needed, sometimes it is, and sometimes just using an invisibility spell works too.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's a longshot, but I would try drinking an invisibility potion. Maybe making yourself invisible will make the game remember to turn you visible when it wears off.

Answer (score 0):

Drinking a Potion that makes you appear in a Spectral Form works, I just tried transforming into the werewolf, it did nothing, sleeping did nothing and drinking a potion of invisibility didn't do anything either. But the potion that turns you into Spectral Form does :)  you end up turning visible after you've been spectral! I have no idea where to find it though....good luck!!

Comment: Is the potion you mentioned, the [Philter of the Phantom](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Philter_of_the_Phantom#Philter_of_the_Phantom)?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it with a potion. It's called Philter of the Phantom which can be found in Shroud Hearth Barrow.