# Why is my character invisible?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I found this question:

[Why have I become invisible?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/48435/why-have-i-become-invisible)

None of the answers are working for me.  That question is over two years old and has no selected answers, so I am considering it a dead question and am asking a new one.  Plus, this may be a different issue because most people appear to encounter this issue after being zapped by Breylin in Winterhold, but this one occurred at random while being attacked by a draugr deathlord in a [Falskaar](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/37994/) dungeon.

My character is invisible.  I can only see the translucent, red glow of my Daedric armor.  When not wearing a helmet and standing before misty/hazy effects such as a waterfall, I can see a ghost-like image of my character.  I've tried the following:

- sexchange twice in console.  Character becomes visible, but goes back to invisible as soon as I close console.
- showracemenu.  Character becomes visible until I exit the race selection screen.
- player.setalpha 100.  Does nothing.
- player.addspell 00030fbe.  player.removespell 00030fbe.  Does nothing.
- player.setnpcweight 0.  Chartacter becomes visible, but invisible again after I close console.
- Become Ethereal shout.  Player becomes visible, but then goes back to invisible.
- Casting other spells with character effects like heal.  Player becomes visible, but then goes back to invisible.
- Becoming ethereal and entering a building.
- Becoming ethereal and waiting.
- Becoming ethereal and fast traveling.  This one almost works.  I appear to become visible permanently, but when I press F1 or F2 to load a new set of armor using SkyUI's hotkeys, I go back to being invisible again.  I'll also note that you have to fast travel far away, not to your current location.
- Turning into werewolf.  Become visible for a few seconds, then back to invisible.
- Sleeping in a bed.
- Waiting for 24 hours.
- Casting Shadowcloak of Nocturnal.  This spell is supposed to make you invisible for 120 seconds.  Instead, I become visible for 120 seconds before going back to invisible.  This one gave me the theory that there must be some visibility flag erroneously set to false.  Shadowcloak then toggles that visibility rather than setting the flag to false, so I become visible until it is toggled again.
- Entering FUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU in console. Did nothing.
- I've come too far to load my last old save that still exists (I pretty much only quick save and all my old autosaves have since been overwritten).

I have been to page 3 of Google over this, so that tells you something.  Is there anything I do to fix this?

Pics related.

[image]

[image]

LOL this is really happening
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I happened upon a fix that supports my theory about the `IsVisible` attribute.  Using another suggestion I found about becoming ethereal and fast traveling, I used Shadowcloak of Nocturnal and fast traveled.  I was always able to tell when my attempts fail after I attempt to switch armor which would always result in me becoming invisible again.  After fast traveling with this spell, I am now able to switch armor and remain visible.  I think this combination of invisibility and fast travel toggled that boolean flag back to its proper value.  Let's hope this stays.

**Update**

Well, it's not *completely* back to normal, but I am not complaining.  My character still appears to be slightly phased.  This pic shows that you can still see through the body.  At least I can see my character now.  What a strange bug.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't look transparent at all in the picture.

Comment: @DCShannon look down and left from the right arm. You can see the house behind them.

Comment: Maybe now that you're halfway there, maybe try some of your previous fixes?

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to just back up to a previous save when the bug occurred. It's happened once to me and once to a follower and both times I just backed up a couple of minutes and was fine.

Answer (score 1):

**This fix is for PC version!**

The problem is most likely caused by a mod that adds a spell effect on you and not clearing the effects after it's done (mods that alter potions or spells for example) which the console commands in the question cannot fix.

The following example fixes vanilla Skyrims Magic effects. Make a text file on the root of the Skyrim folder, it's the same folder where the TESV.exe is (usually C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Skyrim), call it something like **vanilla.txt** and include the following in the file:

```
player.sme 0010D4BD
player.sme 00064459
player.sme 00064458
player.sme 0006D51E
player.sme 000EB7EA
player.sme 00052FF3
player.sme 000C1E8C
player.sme 0001729B
player.sme 000C1E8E
player.sme 000FFCDF
player.sme 000F8753
player.sme 000A1A45
player.sme 000C1E8D
player.sme 0001729D
player.sme 00083589
player.sme 0009BCCB
player.sme 000ED5F2
player.sme 0010C4EB
player.sme 0006BBD0
player.sme 0006C0F3
player.sme 0010CED9
player.sme 0002E1C4
player.sme 00057B49
player.sme 000FEAAA
player.sme 000A1A3F
player.sme 0002E1C5
player.sme 000CDA4B
player.sme 0005312B
player.sme 000ED09F
player.sme 0002E1C6
player.sme 000EEF59
player.sme 00091F77
player.sme 00105F21
player.sme 000424E2
player.sme 00060DA1
player.sme 00104D4A
player.sme 0007F423
player.sme 0001A1EF
player.sme 000C5A9E
player.sme 000D7D55
player.sme 000A852B
player.sme 000F71D2
player.sme 00030B3C
player.sme 0004BB4C
player.sme 0004EFC6
player.sme 000CAF7F
player.sme 000F9066
player.sme 000EB86E
player.sme 000EBEA8
player.sme 0010B2DA
player.sme 0009AA37
player.sme 001090F6
player.sme 0005030E
player.sme 000D2063
player.sme 000D339A
player.sme 000D2053
player.sme 000C5EF6
player.sme 000C7909
player.sme 00103647
player.sme 000D339E
player.sme 001034CB
player.sme 000BF742
player.sme 0010F5A6
player.sme 00072313
player.sme 000CAB90
player.sme 000E40D3
player.sme 00024314
player.sme 00024315
player.sme 00053124
player.sme 000AA024
player.sme 00024318
player.sme 000946F3
player.sme 0008D5BE
player.sme 00091F7A
player.sme 000F1CFE
player.sme 00091F7E
player.sme 000F1D01
player.sme 00091F7D
player.sme 0009AA45
player.sme 0001A4C9
player.sme 0008971F
player.sme 0010F15A
player.sme 0010F158
player.sme 0010F159
player.sme 0010DE1D
player.sme 000ED098
player.sme 000ED096
player.sme 000FD806
player.sme 000FD80A
player.sme 000FD80B
player.sme 000AA01C
player.sme 0008CAC9
player.sme 0002431E
player.sme 0002431F
player.sme 000F0EA7
player.sme 00024324
player.sme 0008CC8B
player.sme 000F1183
player.sme 0008CDD0
player.sme 000AE722
player.sme 00109ADD
player.sme 0003EB42
player.sme 0010AA4A
player.sme 00073F26
player.sme 0003A2B6
player.sme 0010DE5F
player.sme 00073F2B
player.sme 00073F27
player.sme 00073F25
player.sme 0003A2C6
player.sme 0010DE5E
player.sme 00073F2C
player.sme 00073F23
player.sme 0003EB18
player.sme 0003EB24
player.sme 0003EB23
player.sme 0003EB1C
player.sme 0003EB01
player.sme 0003EB25
player.sme 0003EB26
player.sme 0003EB29
player.sme 0003EB06
player.sme 0003EAF3
player.sme 0003EB1E
player.sme 0003EB27
player.sme 0003EB1F
player.sme 0003EB21
player.sme 0003EAF8
player.sme 0003EB07
player.sme 0003EB1B
player.sme 0003EB19
player.sme 000D6947
player.sme 0003EB20
player.sme 0003EB28
player.sme 0003EB1D
player.sme 0003EB22
player.sme 0003EAF9
player.sme 0003EB08
player.sme 0003EB1A
player.sme 00073F29
player.sme 000FF9F8
player.sme 0010FDD4
player.sme 00073F20
player.sme 0003EB3D
player.sme 00073F30
player.sme 0003EAEA
player.sme 0003EAEB
player.sme 00039E51
player.sme 00090041
player.sme 0003EAEC
player.sme 0003EB15
player.sme 000FFA03
player.sme 0003EB17
player.sme 000FFA04
player.sme 0003EB16
player.sme 000FFA05
player.sme 0001B9A7
player.sme 0003AC2D
player.sme 00073F2D
player.sme 00073F2E
player.sme 00073F51
player.sme 00090042
player.sme 00073F2F
player.sme 00051B15
player.sme 000CDB75
player.sme 00059B7A
player.sme 00059B7B
player.sme 00059B7C
player.sme 000173DC
player.sme 0006D22B
player.sme 0006F951
player.sme 0008F3ED
player.sme 0008F3F7
player.sme 000ED397
player.sme 000BB96F
player.sme 000E76E0
player.sme 000F5FFB
player.sme 000E6DF4
player.sme 0001CE9E
player.sme 000424FF
player.sme 0001CEA0
player.sme 00042500
player.sme 0001CE9F
player.sme 000424FA
player.sme 000BA30F
player.sme 000F23F9
player.sme 00050CF2
player.sme 0008BB2D
player.sme 0008BB2B
player.sme 00050CF3
player.sme 0008BB2C
player.sme 00106617
player.sme 00106616
player.sme 0005312C
player.sme 000B62E9
player.sme 0002113F
player.sme 0006F954
player.sme 00050CEE
player.sme 00050CEF
player.sme 00050CEA
player.sme 00050CEB
player.sme 00050CF6
player.sme 00078C11
player.sme 001074FC
player.sme 00050CF9
player.sme 0006F6FC
player.sme 0006F6FD
player.sme 00044C57
player.sme 00090354
player.sme 00109D7C
player.sme 0010FDD1
player.sme 0010FDD3
player.sme 000A26F5
player.sme 0010FDD2
player.sme 00053473
player.sme 00046005
player.sme 000F23D3
player.sme 00104D45
player.sme 00104D44
player.sme 0008BB2A
player.sme 00101063
player.sme 0008D5C5
player.sme 0008D5C6
player.sme 0008D5C4
player.sme 00033975
player.sme 000FBFF5
player.sme 000FCF03
player.sme 00081181
player.sme 00081182
player.sme 000F23CA
player.sme 000F23C7
player.sme 00106E1D
player.sme 000F8300
player.sme 000F82FF
player.sme 00091AE5
player.sme 000EA28E
player.sme 000EA28D
player.sme 0010EBCA
player.sme 0010EBCB
player.sme 0010FAF1
player.sme 000F23FC
player.sme 000EA290
player.sme 000FEE39
player.sme 000FEE35
player.sme 000FEE37
player.sme 000FEE38
player.sme 000FEFBC
player.sme 000D561A
player.sme 000DD026
player.sme 0010F812
player.sme 0010F814
player.sme 000EE5C4
player.sme 00059326
player.sme 0007DCDB
player.sme 0010E38E
player.sme 0009B246
player.sme 000BA1EA
player.sme 000C3EBF
player.sme 000A0D94
player.sme 000F6507
player.sme 000A0D96
player.sme 000A0D97
player.sme 0010C1BC
player.sme 000A05C8
player.sme 0006D22D
player.sme 000F4995
player.sme 000FBFEC
player.sme 000FBFEA
player.sme 000FF15C
player.sme 000A0367
player.sme 000CEDFF
player.sme 001019D8
player.sme 000CEE00
player.sme 001019D9
player.sme 000B79E7
player.sme 001019DA
player.sme 0001EA74
player.sme 001019DB
player.sme 000CE215
player.sme 000B79E8
player.sme 0001EA75
player.sme 000E8269
player.sme 000E826A
player.sme 000B8778
player.sme 00072878
player.sme 000B8777
player.sme 000B877B
player.sme 000B877A
player.sme 000B8775
player.sme 000B8776
player.sme 000B8779
player.sme 000E5F50
player.sme 000E5F53
player.sme 000E5F55
player.sme 000E5F56
player.sme 000E5F59
player.sme 000E5F48
player.sme 0010F20E
player.sme 000369C9
player.sme 000E5F5C
player.sme 000E5F5B
player.sme 000E732B
player.sme 000E5F52
player.sme 000E5F5D
player.sme 0001BAC8
player.sme 000E5F44
player.sme 000E7327
player.sme 000E5F4B
player.sme 0010FC13
player.sme 00016CF3
player.sme 00016D41
player.sme 00016D44
player.sme 00016D46
player.sme 0010F220
player.sme 0010F221
player.sme 0010F21F
player.sme 00105834
player.sme 0009B2B6
player.sme 0009B2B3
player.sme 000B2389
player.sme 000B238A
player.sme 0010E4B2
player.sme 0010E4B0
player.sme 000E4907
player.sme 00101BDC
player.sme 000E4830
player.sme 00086248
player.sme 000D397E
player.sme 0010CB93
player.sme 000FB409
player.sme 000FB407
player.sme 000FB406
player.sme 000FB404
player.sme 0010E949
player.sme 00105831
player.sme 00106E35
player.sme 0010FC23
player.sme 00107E2F
player.sme 00105A01
player.sme 000F82E2
player.sme 0010E834
player.sme 0010582E
player.sme 000E57F4
player.sme 000C1A01
player.sme 000749B3
player.sme 000A88C8
player.sme 000ECFFD
player.sme 000E152A
player.sme 000FB405
player.sme 000FB408
player.sme 000ED5FF
player.sme 000ED600
player.sme 000E5F41
player.sme 0003B0B1
player.sme 000E3CBB
player.sme 000E3CBA
player.sme 0010582C
player.sme 001092A0
player.sme 000AB23C
player.sme 001019D6
player.sme 001019AF
player.sme 00109D12
player.sme 000AA155
player.sme 000AA156
player.sme 000AA157
player.sme 000ACBB5
player.sme 000C5BE0
player.sme 000C5BE1
player.sme 00069CE6
player.sme 0010FC14
player.sme 000F8475
player.sme 0004605A
player.sme 0008B65C
player.sme 0007A0F2
player.sme 0007A0FE
player.sme 00017120
player.sme 000F6906
player.sme 0007A0F3
player.sme 0007A0F4
player.sme 0007A0F5
player.sme 0007A0F6
player.sme 000F81E2
player.sme 0007A0F8
player.sme 000493AA
player.sme 0007A0F9
player.sme 0007A0FA
player.sme 0007A0FB
player.sme 0007A0FC
player.sme 00049504
player.sme 0007A0FD
player.sme 000F81E5
player.sme 0007A0FF
player.sme 000D6933
player.sme 0007A100
player.sme 0007A101
player.sme 0008850D
player.sme 0007A102
player.sme 0007A103
player.sme 0007A104
player.sme 00049507
player.sme 0007A105
player.sme 0007A106
player.sme 0004605B
player.sme 000BEE94
player.sme 0005B451
player.sme 000BEE93
player.sme 0005B44F
player.sme 0010E809
player.sme 00092A57
player.sme 000ACBB6
player.sme 00100E60
player.sme 00048C8B
player.sme 00048F45
player.sme 000B7A35
player.sme 000FF15E
player.sme 00049295
player.sme 0010962E
player.sme 0010962F
player.sme 00109631
player.sme 00109632
player.sme 00109633
player.sme 00109630
player.sme 00109634
player.sme 00109635
player.sme 00109636
player.sme 00109637
player.sme 00109638
player.sme 0004605C
player.sme 0010B116
player.sme 000F5D24
player.sme 0005B452
player.sme 0005B450
player.sme 000F5D15
player.sme 0005B46B
player.sme 00092A48
player.sme 000F871B
player.sme 0003AE9E
player.sme 00013CA9
player.sme 0010CBDD
player.sme 00012F03
player.sme 0010F7F1
player.sme 0001CEA1
player.sme 0007A82A
player.sme 00082A32
player.sme 00082A33
player.sme 000C5C0A
player.sme 000D4889
player.sme 000E771F
player.sme 000E9AC7
player.sme 0010C645
player.sme 001058A5
player.sme 001058A8
player.sme 001058A6
player.sme 001058A4
player.sme 000F33CB
player.sme 001058A2
player.sme 001058A7
player.sme 000F33CC
player.sme 001058A3
player.sme 000FB991
player.sme 000FB98D
player.sme 000FB98E
player.sme 000FB989
player.sme 000FB98A
player.sme 000FB990
player.sme 000FB992
player.sme 0010E8AF
player.sme 000FB993
player.sme 000FB98F
player.sme 000FB98B
player.sme 000EA65A
player.sme 0003AEA0
player.sme 00013CAA
player.sme 0010CBDE
player.sme 0001CEA2
player.sme 0010F7F0
player.sme 0001CEA3
player.sme 000EA076
player.sme 0007E8E2
player.sme 00066335
player.sme 00066334
player.sme 000B79FC
player.sme 000B79FD
player.sme 000B79FE
player.sme 000B729D
player.sme 000B729F
player.sme 000B72A0
player.sme 000B72A1
player.sme 000E755A
player.sme 000F4578
player.sme 000B92CD
player.sme 0002FB1F
player.sme 00080E33
player.sme 000225BA
player.sme 00022477
player.sme 000592D5
player.sme 0003104B
player.sme 0010CDCC
player.sme 0010F7A4
player.sme 0010E3CF
player.sme 00044F55
player.sme 000D205A
player.sme 000D205C
player.sme 001031D5
player.sme 00103964
player.sme 000E827E
player.sme 000E827F
player.sme 000E8280
player.sme 000E0CD0
player.sme 000E0CD2
player.sme 0004E80B
player.sme 0008F3F2
player.sme 0002ACD4
player.sme 0003E07B
player.sme 000E0CD4
player.sme 00045D5A
player.sme 000E5F6B
player.sme 000E5F6A
player.sme 000E5F69
player.sme 000CF789
player.sme 000CF78A
player.sme 000CF78B
player.sme 000CF796
player.sme 000CF797
player.sme 000CF798
player.sme 000CF79C
player.sme 000CF7A3
player.sme 000CF7A4
player.sme 0004DEE7
player.sme 0004DEDF
player.sme 0007E8DC
player.sme 0004DEE6
player.sme 0001EA78
player.sme 0007E8D6
player.sme 0001EA77
player.sme 0001EA7A
player.sme 0007E8D8
player.sme 0001EA79
player.sme 0001EA76
player.sme 00026D7C
player.sme 00026D7E
player.sme 0010F9B8
player.sme 0001EA6B
player.sme 0001EA6A
player.sme 00072312
player.sme 0001EA6D
player.sme 0001EA6C
player.sme 0010E72F
player.sme 0010E731
player.sme 0010E730
player.sme 000F5FF6
player.sme 000CDA1F
player.sme 0009152E
player.sme 00055CE6
player.sme 0010E80A
player.sme 0010E80C
player.sme 0010E80D
player.sme 0010E80E
player.sme 0010E80F
player.sme 000F82B5
player.sme 000239A1
player.sme 0010BF17
player.sme 000C28F4
player.sme 0010815D
player.sme 00082A52
player.sme 00082A50
player.sme 0006A156
player.sme 001076EE
player.sme 001076EF
player.sme 001076F6
player.sme 001076FF
player.sme 001076ED
player.sme 000E1FEF
player.sme 000E1FEC
player.sme 000EA5EB
player.sme 00106B11
player.sme 0006A10B
player.sme 000B323F
player.sme 00097EE2
player.sme 00097EE1
player.sme 0006A154
player.sme 00099F35
player.sme 000EF962
player.sme 000EF95D
player.sme 000EF95E
player.sme 0010757F
player.sme 0002F2DD
player.sme 0010FF0C
player.sme 000F1AC2
player.sme 000FF9F7
player.sme 000FF8D9
player.sme 0010387B
player.sme 00103B04
player.sme 0010A2DB
player.sme 0010EB61
player.sme 0010FDD7
player.sme 001034C0
player.sme 0009DD4E
player.sme 0008F3E9
player.sme 0008F3EA
player.sme 000EBB78
player.sme 0006B10C
player.sme 000D9DAF
player.sme 0010F84C
player.sme 0001EA6E
player.sme 0006F702
player.sme 000B62E5
player.sme 0009AA3F
player.sme 00106AEB
player.sme 00104AB5
player.sme 00104ABA
player.sme 00104AB9
player.sme 000A3F62
player.sme 000C367A
player.sme 000CAB61
player.sme 000CAB64
player.sme 000CAB63
player.sme 000CAB62
player.sme 00101061
player.sme 0009CD50
player.sme 000F3934
player.sme 000F3932
player.sme 000F3935
player.sme 000F3936
player.sme 0009CD4B
player.sme 000F3F0C
player.sme 000F3F10
player.sme 000F3F0D
player.sme 000F3F0F
player.sme 00108A3E
player.sme 0010E4FA
player.sme 0010E4FB
player.sme 0010E4FC
player.sme 00096591
player.sme 000AF667
player.sme 0010C4E6
player.sme 000C1E98
player.sme 000C1E9A
player.sme 000153D3
player.sme 000F392F
player.sme 000F392D
player.sme 000F3930
player.sme 000F3931
player.sme 000A6A3B
player.sme 0009E0BB
player.sme 0009E0BC
player.sme 0009E0BD
player.sme 0009E0BE
player.sme 0009E0BF
player.sme 0009E0C0
player.sme 00050CF4
player.sme 00050CF0
player.sme 00050CF5
player.sme 00050CF1
player.sme 0009E0C1
player.sme 0009E0C2
player.sme 0009E0C3
player.sme 0009E0C4
player.sme 0009E0C5
player.sme 00050CEC
player.sme 00050CED
player.sme 000AF669
player.sme 0009379B
player.sme 000D799D
player.sme 000954D4
player.sme 000D8C32
player.sme 00105F17
player.sme 00108A41
player.sme 0004E93E
player.sme 0004250D
player.sme 0004E93F
player.sme 0004250E
player.sme 000B62F2
player.sme 0009E0C7
player.sme 0009E0C6
player.sme 00026D7A
player.sme 000D799F
player.sme 00103AD7
player.sme 0004E945
player.sme 0010EE4A
player.sme 0010EE40
player.sme 0004E946
player.sme 0010EE4B
player.sme 0010EE44
player.sme 0004E947
player.sme 000728BF
player.sme 000CC798
player.sme 00105F1B
player.sme 000E826D
player.sme 00106255
player.sme 000954D6
player.sme 000F5B57
player.sme 00106395
player.sme 000D4FF1
player.sme 000B8F30
player.sme 000E40D6
player.sme 000E40C6
player.sme 000E40C7
player.sme 0010EAD0
player.sme 000E40C9
player.sme 0010C4E7
player.sme 000E40C2
player.sme 000E40BF
player.sme 000E40CD
player.sme 000E40D0
player.sme 00065BD6
player.sme 00096D0B
player.sme 00096D0C
player.sme 00096D0D
player.sme 00016B4B
player.sme 00016C0F
player.sme 00016C3B
player.sme 00016C3D
player.sme 000F52AB
player.sme 0010EAD9
player.sme 0007E8E0
player.sme 0010D96C
player.sme 0010D968
player.sme 0010D96B
player.sme 0001CEA5
player.sme 0001CEA4
player.sme 0001CEA7
player.sme 0001CEA6
player.sme 000B62F0
player.sme 000B62ED
player.sme 000DD642
player.sme 0010E833
player.sme 000F4996
player.sme 0002F3B9
player.sme 0002F3BA
player.sme 0005DB8F
player.sme 0006796D
player.sme 0006796E
player.sme 0000014A
player.sme 000877E9
player.sme 0010CAAB
player.sme 00017331
player.sme 0010CAAD
player.sme 000FCC62
player.sme 0003AEA1
player.sme 000E4CB6
player.sme 00013CAB
player.sme 0010CBDF
player.sme 0001CEA8
player.sme 0010F7EF
player.sme 0005DBAE
player.sme 0004EFDE
player.sme 000D22FA
player.sme 0004DBA3
player.sme 000B3C9E
player.sme 000B3CA2
player.sme 000B3C9A
player.sme 000B3C9C
player.sme 000B3CA0
player.sme 000A8528
player.sme 000CB12C
player.sme 001090F9
player.sme 000AE782
player.sme 00039D41
player.sme 000B8F52
player.sme 000C5C0B
player.sme 00104D41
player.sme 0007809B
player.sme 000A44C0
player.sme 0010AB4A
player.sme 0010FC12
player.sme 0010DDED
player.sme 000640B4
player.sme 0001CEAA
player.sme 0007E5D2
player.sme 000CDECF
player.sme 0009CE2B
player.sme 0001CEAB
player.sme 0010EE48
player.sme 0007E5D3
player.sme 000CDED0
player.sme 0001CEAC
player.sme 0010EE49
player.sme 0007E5D4
player.sme 000CDED1
player.sme 0001A4CB
player.sme 0006E1DD
player.sme 000D61E2
player.sme 000FB8D4
player.sme 000FDBC2
player.sme 000FDBB8
player.sme 000FDBC5
player.sme 000F6516
player.sme 000F6515
player.sme 000F1989
player.sme 000FDBBF
player.sme 00017121
player.sme 001058A9
player.sme 000F198A
player.sme 000FDBC8
player.sme 000F198B
player.sme 000FCC27
player.sme 00109110
player.sme 0010A251
player.sme 0010A252
player.sme 0010A253
player.sme 0010A24B
player.sme 0010A254
player.sme 0010A255
player.sme 0010A26E
player.sme 0010A26F
player.sme 0010A270
player.sme 0010A271
player.sme 0010A272
player.sme 0010A273
player.sme 00101928
player.sme 0010192A
player.sme 00101929
player.sme 0010A285
player.sme 00101930
player.sme 0010192F
player.sme 0010192E
player.sme 000E6060
player.sme 00109E75
player.sme 00109E76
player.sme 00109E77
player.sme 00109E78
player.sme 00109E79
player.sme 00109E7A
player.sme 00101931
player.sme 0009F28F
player.sme 00073322
player.sme 0010A274
player.sme 0010A275
player.sme 0010A276
player.sme 0010A277
player.sme 0010A278
player.sme 00073270
player.sme 0010A279
player.sme 0010A27A
player.sme 0010A27B
player.sme 0010A27C
player.sme 0010A27D
player.sme 00073325
player.sme 0010A280
player.sme 0010A281
player.sme 0010A282
player.sme 0010A283
player.sme 0010A284
player.sme 0010192D
player.sme 0010192C
player.sme 0010192B
player.sme 0004B145
player.sme 0005DD5B
player.sme 0005DD5C
player.sme 0004D3F7
player.sme 0005DD5F
player.sme 0008C1AA
player.sme 0004D3F9
player.sme 000EA075
player.sme 0010DE1A
player.sme 0010DE1B
player.sme 0010DE18
player.sme 0010DE17
player.sme 0010DE19
player.sme 000F5B55
player.sme 0010F1E6
player.sme 0010DE1C
player.sme 000C4DDE
player.sme 0009E0C8
player.sme 0009E0CA
player.sme 0009E0CB
player.sme 0010E4FD
player.sme 0010319E
player.sme 0008AFCB
player.sme 00049454
player.sme 000FEAD1
player.sme 00051963
player.sme 00051965
player.sme 00051966
player.sme 00078B9D
player.sme 00078B9F
player.sme 00078BA1
player.sme 0003F508
player.sme 0003F509
player.sme 0003F50A
player.sme 0008BB26
player.sme 000CD088
player.sme 000CD089
player.sme 00023959
player.sme 0002395C
player.sme 0002395D
player.sme 0007B6BA
player.sme 0007B6BB
player.sme 0007B6BC
player.sme 000F80FC
player.sme 000252C1
player.sme 000549B4
player.sme 000DD605
player.sme 00017192
player.sme 00044255
player.sme 0003EA30
player.sme 0002C56F
player.sme 0002C593
player.sme 00020E16
player.sme 000562EA
player.sme 000562EB
player.sme 0005D16F
player.sme 0005D170
player.sme 0005D171
player.sme 000A0366
player.sme 0010E4F6
player.sme 0010E4F7
player.sme 0010E4F8
player.sme 00082A37
player.sme 00082A36
player.sme 00082A38
player.sme 0006E0C1
player.sme 00064D68
player.sme 0010319D
player.sme 0010319C
player.sme 0002F2D2
player.sme 00048ACD
player.sme 0002F7B9
player.sme 0004372F
player.sme 00043730
player.sme 000A1A58
player.sme 000E3F0A
player.sme 000A1A5C
player.sme 000E3F09
player.sme 000A1A5B
player.sme 000D5E81
player.sme 000E771B
player.sme 000E771D
player.sme 000ECEB5
player.sme 0007430D
player.sme 000D5F1B
player.sme 00013E08
player.sme 0007F82E
player.sme 0007F82F
player.sme 0000014C
player.sme 0005AD60
player.sme 0005AD61
player.sme 000CD82F
player.sme 0001EA73
player.sme 0010F99E
player.sme 00092C45
player.sme 000F8209
player.sme 000EC356
player.sme 000E5F63
player.sme 0010CAAA
player.sme 000F1188
player.sme 000F117F
player.sme 000EFC60
player.sme 000EFC62
```

Save the file, open the console in Skyrim and write **bat vanilla**.
It removes the spell effects added by any potion/spell/mod that alters the vanilla effects and should restore the character to normal. Note that you need to re-equip your equipments to re-apply the enchant effects.

I found this from Skyrim Nexus forums on the following thread and it contains other fixes for the DLC's and some mods that add new effects:

> Batch files have been made by LebitelSofta that will remove all vanilla Skyrim, Dawnguard, Dragonborn, WetnCold[sic] and Skyrim Immersive Creatures visual and shader effects from the player

[TUTORIAL: REMOVING UNWANTED MAGIC EFFECTS FROM THE PLAYER](https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/872861-tutorial-removing-unwanted-magic-effects-from-the-player/)

You need account to download the files for the other fixes, I included the vanilla file as an example. But if you can figure out the spell that's causing the problem you can remove it manually yourself with the player.sms - this is however a fast way to fix any spell that's causing trouble.

Also note that if you download the files, you have to manually edit the dlc and mod txt files:

> Edit the Dawnguard, Dragonborn, or WC or SIC batch files (if necessary) so that every shader or effect ID matches your load order.

Answer (score -1):

The hair in your screenshots looks like the Apachee hair mod, so I'm going to assume you have other mods as well. Reinstall all mods related to character appearance, behavior, or magic.
If that doesn't work, make a new gamesave just to make sure your current one hasn't been corrupted.

Comment: The OP already found a solution (or a compromise in this case) to their problem (they self answered).  Although adding additional answers is fine, this post is nearing 3 years old, and probably wouldn't benefit any further from your answer.  Your answer also makes assumptions that mods are present, which are typically not good answers.

Answer (score -1):

FOR PC USERS ONLY.

open up console commands, by pressing '' ` ''

click on your character and type in console commands

resurrect

Answer (score -2):

I had this same problem and I just fixed it without going back to the spot that it happened, and losing my progress. All I did was use the shout “become ethereal”. I used it just for fun to see what it did and my character just popped up again.

Answer (score -3):

Use the ethereal shout.  It corrected mine.  487 mods 254 .esps

Answer (score -4):

Just hit the guards and let you be killed. It worked for me

Answer (score -5):

It's the goddamn Wet and Cold mod.

https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/872861-tutorial-removing-unwanted-magic-effects-from-the-player/

Solution 4 has an option for wet and cold effects as well.

That's what I figured out after 6 hours of futzing around with this.